# Batch create folder by date from filenames

Tags: batch-file

The best I've come up with is:

```
for %%i in (*) do md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
```

The problem right now is I'm creating a folder for every file and moving all the files to the respective folders but related content is now in different folders and things with the exact same filename is getting left in the main folder.

I have files in folder:

```
sadf_02.07.2018_sadfff.xlsx
sadf_03.07.2018_fgtrh.xlsx
suyuadf_05.07.2018_uktyuk.xlsx
sarthdf_05.07.2018_sadyukyfff.xlsx
sabbdf_05.07.2018_saukyukdfff.xlsx
```

I need to create folders by dates in names and move this file inside this folder

so I should have:

```
02.07.2018
    sadf_02.07.2018_sadfff.xlsx
03.07.2018
    sadf_03.07.2018_fgtrh.xlsx
05.07.2018
    suyuadf_05.07.2018_uktyuk.xlsx
    sarthdf_05.07.2018_sadyukyfff.xlsx
    sabbdf_05.07.2018_saukyukdfff.xlsx
```

So how to accomplish that?

Comment: Depending upon your needs you'd want to use a `For /F` loop delimiting on `_`. And possibly, for safety, a regular expression search for the possible, `dd.MM.yyyy` patterns. _When working with regex and dates, utilising other languages is often recommended_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following batch uses:

- a simple for to enumerate the files in %%A
- a for /f to split the file name at the underscore and get the date to %%B
- passes the date to findstr and coarsely checks the structure
- creates the date folder if not there
- finally moves the files

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\25\SO_51513265.cmd
@Echo off
PushD "X:\Folder\to\start" || (Echo couldn't find folder&pause&Exit /b 1)

For %%A in (*_*_*.xlsx) Do For /f "tokens=2delims=_" %%B in ("%%A") Do (
  Echo=%%B|Findstr "^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.20[0-9][0-9]$" 2>&1>NUL && (
  if not exist "%%B" MD "%%B">NUL
  Move "%%A" "%%B\"
  )
)
```

Sample tree after running the batch:

```
> tree /f
├───02.07.2018
│       sadf_02.07.2018_sadfff.xlsx
│
├───03.07.2018
│       sadf_03.07.2018_fgtrh.xlsx
│
└───05.07.2018
        sarthdf_05.07.2018_sadyukyfff.xlsx
        suyuadf_05.07.2018_uktyuk.xlsx
```

Comment: How to change `PushD "X:\Folder\to\start" || (Echo couldn't find folder&pause&Exit /b 1)` to folder where script is?

Comment: Change it to the path where the *.xlsx files are located. Or removew the entire line if in the same location.

Comment: I have > 100 folders each time change variable?

Comment: Cite: `I have files in folder:` if there are more folders/subfolders. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51513265/edit) your question to supply more information.

Comment: Works but very slow

Comment: Do it by hand and compare ;-)